# PFSENSE - Squid - Transparent Mode not working correctly

Tags: squid, pfsense

I am having this weird problem with squid (both squid and squid 3). After installing, i forwarded all my traffic from mikrotik in port `3128` but the requests seemed to fail. After researching I noticed that even when I selected Transparent mode in gui,in config file it was missing after ip addres. `http_port 192.168.88.13:3128` `http_port 127.0.0.1:3128 transparent`
After modifying manually config and adding transparent, it works but it's not stable. Config now looks like this: `http_port 192.168.88.13:3128 transparent` `http_port 127.0.0.1:3128 transparent`